# Quickbase and Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, quickbase

I've done a ton of research on this and I've seen people asking this, but never seen an answer: Is there any way that anyone has discovered to work with the Docusign API from within Quickbase? As far as I can tell, quickbase only supports Javascript, without Node.js, and Docusign doesn't support CORS. I tried talking to both companies who won't say it isn't possible, but aren't really giving me any direction beyond the official docs, which aren't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### December 2023 update

DocuSign eSignature REST API now supports CORS. So now you can make direct API calls from JavaScript in the browser to DocuSign. Use the oauth implicit grant to obtain an access token.

### Original 2017 answer

I suggest that you build a small Gateway that will support cors on one side and the DocuSign API on the other side

Comment: Yes, we were trying to avoid building anything outside of quickbase, but it appears that may be the only solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a combination of middleware like Workato and an AWS lamdba function to leverage Docusign and Quickbase.

Second option is to use a plugin from Juiced Tech which integrates Docusign with an easy UI.